# How to implement `.nf` formatting feature

Tags: c, formatting, user-input

I have written a program that reads a text file inputted by the user, and inside the file contains formatting features such as `.br` , `.sp` and `.nf`.

`.nf` symbolises no fill, also meaning that when you see any formatting feature after `.nf` they should all be ignored and it should just output the text in the format it originally appears in the text file.

For example:

```
.nf Hello my name is .br Jay.
```

Output:

```
Hello my name is Jay
```

If `.nf` was not there the output would be:

```
Hello my name is 
Jay.
```

Here's my code:

```
int main(void) {
    FILE *fp = NULL;
    char file_name[257] = {'\0'};
    char line[61] = {'\0'};
    char word[61] = {'\0'};
    int out = 0;
    int blanks;
    int space;
    int useFormats = 1;

    printf ( "Enter file name:\n");
    scanf ( " %256[^\n]", file_name);

    if ( ( fp = fopen ( file_name, "r")) == NULL) {
        printf ( "could not open file\n");
        return 1;
    }
    while (useFormats == 1){
        while ( ( fscanf ( fp, "%60s", word)) == 1) { //breaks the sentence    after .br
            if ( strcmp ( word, ".br") == 0) {
                printf ( "%s\n", line);
                line[0] = '\0';
                out = 1;
            }

            if ( strcmp ( word, ".nf") == 0) {// stop filling lines (no fill)
                useFormats == 0;
                line[0] = '\0';
                out = 1;

            }

            if ( strncmp ( word, ".sp", 3) == 0) { // creates n amount of spaces after .sp
                if ( ( sscanf ( &word[3], "%d", &blanks)) == 1) {
                    printf ( "%s\n", line);
                    while ( blanks) {
                        blanks--;
                        printf ( "\n");
                    }
                    line[0] = '\0';
                    out = 1;
                } 
                else {
                    printf ( "%s\n", line);
                    line[0] = '\0';
                    out = 1;
                }
            }
            else if ( strlen ( line) + strlen ( word) + 1 < 60) {
                strcat ( line, " ");
                strcat ( line, word);
                out = 0;
            }
            else {
                printf ( "%s\n", line);
                strcpy ( line, word);
                out = 1;
            }
        }
        if ( !out) {
            printf ( "%s\n", line);
        }

        fclose ( fp);
        return 0;
    }
}
```

I tried creating a variable called `useFormats` which is true whilst running and I make it false when it reaches to the `.nf` feature but nothing happens. I'm not sure if I should remove the `if` statement and create another `while` loop to say `while (useFormats == 0)` to implement the `.nf` feature.

Comment: I tried adding another condition but the formatting features after `.nf` still work

Comment: Yeah I think thats where i'm a bit stuck, on how to skip the other if statements when `useFormats =0;`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should capture the `".nf"` token and set useFormats to zero. Adding `if ( useFormats == 1) {` to the other format conditions should disable them.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

#define WIDTH 80

int main(void) {
    FILE *fp = NULL;
    char file_name[257] = {'\0'};
    char line[61] = {'\0'};
    char word[61] = {'\0'};
    int out = 0;
    int blanks = 0;
    int center = 0;
    int useFormats = 1;
    int margin = 0;

    printf ( "Enter file name:\n");
    scanf ( " %256[^\n]", file_name);

    if ( ( fp = fopen ( file_name, "r")) == NULL) {
        printf ( "could not open file\n");
        return 1;
    }

    while ( ( fscanf ( fp, "%60s", word)) == 1) {// read file to end one word at a time
        if ( strcmp ( word, ".nf") == 0) {// no formatting)
            useFormats = 0;
            center = 0;
            continue;
        }
        if ( strncmp ( word, ".ce", 3) == 0) {
            if ( useFormats == 1) {
                if ( ( sscanf ( &word[3], "%d", &center)) != 1) {
                    center = 0;
                }
            }
            continue;
        }
        if ( strncmp ( word, ".sp", 3) == 0) {
            if ( useFormats == 1) {
                if ( ( sscanf ( &word[3], "%d", &blanks)) == 1) {
                    margin = 0;
                    if ( center) {
                        margin = WIDTH - ( ( WIDTH - strlen ( line)) / 2);
                        center--;
                    }
                    printf ( "%*s\n", margin, line);
                    while ( blanks) {
                        blanks--;
                        printf ( "\n");
                    }
                    line[0] = '\0';
                    out = 1;
                }
                else {
                    margin = 0;
                    if ( center) {
                        margin = WIDTH - ( ( WIDTH - strlen ( line)) / 2);
                        center--;
                    }
                    printf ( "%*s\n", margin, line);
                    line[0] = '\0';
                    out = 1;
                }
            }
            continue;
        }
        if ( strcmp ( word, ".br") == 0) {
            if ( useFormats == 1) {
                margin = 0;
                if ( center) {
                    margin = WIDTH - ( ( WIDTH - strlen ( line)) / 2);
                    center--;
                }
                printf ( "%*s\n", margin, line);
                line[0] = '\0';
                out = 1;
            }
            continue;
        }
        if ( strlen ( line) + strlen ( word) + 1 <= 60) {
            strcat ( line, " ");
            strcat ( line, word);
            out = 0;
        }
        else {
            margin = 0;
            if ( center) {
                margin = WIDTH - ( ( WIDTH - strlen ( line)) / 2);
                center--;
            }
            printf ( "%*s\n", margin, line);
            strcpy ( line, word);
            out = 1;
        }
    }
    if ( !out) {
        margin = 0;
        if ( center) {
            margin = ( WIDTH - strlen ( line)) / 2;
            center--;
        }
        printf ( "%*s\n", margin, line);
    }

    fclose ( fp);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: thank you so much that helped a lot, I was still trying to see where I went wrong

Answer (score 0):

As long as this: `while ( ( fscanf ( fp, "%60s", word)) == 1)` evaluates as true it will never break from the while current inner while loop. You can break out of the inner while loop with `break;` after your condition is met. It will then check the condition and break out of the main while loop. You also don't assign a value with ==. That operand is for evaluation.

```
if ( strcmp ( word, ".nf") == 0) {// stop filling lines (no fill)
        useFormats = 0;
        line[0] = '\0';
        out = 1;
        break;
    }
```

Comment: Yeah thats exactly what I tried earlier, but thanks i'll try it again

Comment: Above you;ll see the edit that assigns a value with `=` instead of evaluating `==`. It also has `break` at the end of the block which while force you to break out of the current inner loop.

Comment: do I still put that `if` statement inside the while loop `while useFormats == 1` or do I get rid of the while loop

Comment: if you want to stop running the inner loop when you find .nf then you can get rid of the outer loop and useFormats altogether and just keep `break;` to get you out of the while loop

Comment: I think theres something wrong with my program because whichever way I do it, it literally just prints the first line of code then ends the whole program